# Using Eclipse JDT to parse java files

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I use Eclipse JDT library to parse java source code to visit all methods defined in classes. When the code contains comment like "//xxxx" in the body of the method, the parser will stop before the comment, and the method main(String[] args) was ignored.

This is the sample case for parsing:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    private String name;
    private int age; 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
                //Set the age
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        if(true) {
            hw.setAge(10);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code I write to parse the above sample case:

```
public class Parser {

/**
 * Parse java program in given file path
 * @param filePath
 */
public void parseFile(String filePath) {
    System.out.println("Starting to parse " + filePath);
    char[] source = readCharFromFile(filePath);
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(source);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void endVisit(MethodDeclaration node) {
            System.out.println("Method " + node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName() + " is visited");
        }

    });
}
}
```

When I use it to parse the code, it can only get the result that method `getName()`, `setName()`, `getAge()` and `getAge()` have been visited while `main()` is ignored.

Looking forward to your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to problem with the code you are using to read the source.

Try this code below to read the file :

```
File javaFile = new File(filePath);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(javaFile));
final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while (null != (line = in.readLine())) {
     buffer.append(line).append("\n");
}
```

and use this to set your parser source :

```
parser.setSource(buffer.toString().toCharArray());
```

Everything else seems to be fine with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `readCharFromFile(filePath)` method removes `\n` or end-of-line characters from the file. This means that all lines after the comment are actually part of the comment.

Comment: It really strips \n characters?  Why would that be useful functionality? Pretty funny if true.